# Firebase: get more information about attendees attending an event

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

With Firebase (Web) I am trying to get useful information from my event

My database structure:

```
{
    users:
        "abc": {
            birthday: "21/07/1998",
            firstname: "Maxime",
            lastLogin: "30/07/2018"
        },
        "def": {
            birthday: "12/03/1973",
            firstname: "John",
            lastLogin: "12/04/2018"
        },
    },

    events: {
        "df16s5dfs21er6zf5f1ze-": {
            title: "Some great event",
            members: [
                "abc", 
                "def"
            ]
        } 
    }
}
```

What I try to obtain in Javascript is an object containing all my events, the members of those events and some more information about those members. So for example:

```
{
    "df16s5dfs21er6zf5f1ze-": {
        title: "Some great event",
        members: {
            "abc": {
                firstname: "Maxime",
                lastLogin: "30/07/2018"
            },
            "def": {
                firstname: "John",
                lastLogin: "12/04/2018"
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

As you can see the only things that have been added is "firstname" and "lastLogin" that should be fetched directly from the "users" node.

I tried multiple things in Javascript, without success :(

Does anybody has a good example of a solution that can handle this situation?

My code at the moment:

```
let refEvents   = firebase.database().ref("/events");
let refUsers    = firebase.database().ref("/users");

refEvents
    .once('value')
    .then((snapEvents) => {
        snapEvents.forEach((snapEvent, kEvent) => {
            let event = snapEvent.val();
            // Iterate on event.members and write this info into event.members[key_member] = memberData;
        });
    });
```

EDIT:

I tried the following, I think I am just missing async(s) / await(s)

```
    refEvents
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
        let events = snapshot.val();

        for(kEvent in events) {
            console.log(kEvent, "Is an event");
            let event = events[kEvent];

            for(member in event.members) { 
                console.log(member, "Is a member of event", kEvent);
                refUsers.child(member).child("/profile").once('value', (userProfile) => {
                    console.log("userProfile", userProfile);
                });
            }
        }

        console.log("final events", events);
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_EVENTS_S, payload: cleanNewEvents(snapshot.val()) });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_EVENTS_F, payload: err.message });
    });
```

The problem here is that the 'userProfile' logs are coming after execution of the loop.

Comment: I will suggest you post the "tried solutions" because I don't think you will have any issue in your code for accessing each users details. My guess is your issue is **where** you are trying to use the values ('firstname' & 'lastLogin') of users. Note that when you are going to fetch the user details, the call is async and you will need to rely on a collection of promises to know when all data is received.

Comment: @VivekAthalye yes indeed but the issue is that I don’t really know how to handle this case with promises. I couldn’t make my first request (events) wait until it fetched all of my members (second request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to handle this case**

*Fetch events*

```
export const fetchEvents = async () => {
    let finalEvents = {};
    let events = await getEvents();
        events = events.val();

    for(kEvent in events) {
        let event   = events[kEvent];
        let members = await getMembers(event.members);

        event.members = members;

        finalEvents[kEvent] = event;
    }

    return finalEvents;
}
```

*Get events function*

```
const getEvents = () => {
    return firebase
        .database()
        .ref("events")
        .once("value");
}
```

*Get members for one event*

```
const getMembers = async (members) => {
    let profiles = {};

    for(member in members) {
        let profile             = await getProfile(member);
        let { username , image } = profile.val();

        if(!image) image = "";

        profiles[member] = { username, image };
    }

    return profiles;
}
```

*Get profile of one member*

```
const getProfile = (kUser) => {
    return firebase
        .database()
        .ref("users")
        .child(kUser)
        .child("profile")
        .once("value");
}
```